# I understand yarn is an alternative to npm; how can I use it offline mode?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I usually work with npm, recently I was being suggested yarn is a better alternative, as it can be used to cache the node_modules locally and save network bandwidth.

yarn is not working when I'm off network. can any one help me out?

Comment: Did you even attempt to google "yarn offline"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yarn by default works in online mode, unless it is launched using its offline switch.

```
yarn install –offline
```

However, the above command works only when yarn is preconfigured with a offline cache. the below commands will help to get it done.

- `yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror ./npm-packages-offline-cache`
- `yarn config set yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true`

for a detailed reading, please go through this blog, https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/